# Center text with background CSS "shape"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "cancel" link that looks like an x with a solid red circle behind it.

Here is the CSS:

```
.circle {
  display:inline;
  padding-left:4px;
  padding-right:4px;
  background:rgb(196,15,24);
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}

.circle a {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class='circle'>
  <a href="">x</a>
</div>
```

It ends up looking like this: [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/472563dfe4.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/472563dfe4.png).

How do I move the x so that it is centered within the circle? Changing the `margin-top` or `bottom` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you relatively position your a tag you can fix it:

```
.circle a {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;

  position:relative; top:-2px;
}
```

Adjust the `top` value to your liking.

Comment: Maybe padding-bottom would do the trick here too, but I know Internet Explorer is (or has been) picky about vertical paddings on inline elements (it crops stuff that extends beyond the line height).

Answer (score 1):

Your font must accomodate characters like É, q, X and x, etc and still be displayed over background whatever the height of the character is.

I found that using an `X` (or `text-transform: uppercase;` obviously) and `font-family: monospace;` was an improvement with your code, though not perfect. Solution provided by mhr is useful even with a monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar, and using the following to center my text:

```
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
```